# ディスプレイの解像度とアプリで取得したウィンドウサイズの値とが一致しないのはなぜ？

Tags: c#

フォームアプリで、アプリを最大化し、フルHDモニターで横幅を取得したところ、1920では無く1936が返ってきました。
これは正しいのでしょうか？
縦は1080ではなく1096でした

```
label1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
label2.Text = this.Height.ToString();
```

PCはレッツノート、マウスコンピュータで試しましたが、どちらも同じでした。
実際に横幅が1936なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プログラムのフォームのサイズとモニターのサイズの情報は別物です。

フォームの縦横サイズプロパティの値には上下左右の枠線部分が含まれますが、表示を最大化した場合には枠線は表示されません。
その差が違いとなって値が変わってきます。
例えばこんな記事が参考になるでしょう。
[フォームのサイズ（幅と高さ）を取得／設定する [C#]](https://johobase.com/windows-form-size/)
[フォームのクライアント領域のサイズを取得／設定する [C#]](https://johobase.com/windows-form-clientsize/)

モニターのサイズを取得したいのなら、こちらの記事が参考になるでしょう。
[ディスプレイの大きさ（画面の領域、解像度）を取得する](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/system/displaysize.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。疑問なのは横1920で作成したアプリを、モニターの中央に表示すると、左右に少し背景が見えるのですが、モニターのサイズが1920でアプリのサイズが1920であれば、背景は見えないはずだと思いました。従いまして、モニターのサイズが少しし大きいのか、C#の設定が少し小さいのかのどちらかだと思うのですが、このあたりがよくわかっていません。上記を参考に調べてみます。

Comment: おそらく、その「背景は見えないはず」という想定が実情と合っていないのでしょう。@sayuri さんが書いたようにOSバージョンやテーマあるいはフォームのスタイル指定によって、枠線の部分をどのようなサイズ・描画内容にするかが変わってくるのだと思われます。Aeroの有無とかもありますしね。例えば特に設定変更していなければウィンドウの周囲に薄い影のような領域が表示されていますので、つまり枠線の部分は半透明で背景が透けて見えるのでしょう。

Comment: 承知いたしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

最大化を解除すると、ウィンドウ枠の外側に半透明の影が見えると思います。その部分を含んだサイズとなっています。OSバージョンやテーマによっても変わってきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。kunifさんの回答へのコメントにも書きましたが、横1920で作成したアプリをフルHDのモニターの中央に表示すると、左右にわずかに背景が見えてしまいます。アプリが1920でモニターサイズが1920であれば背景は見えないと思いますが、これはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 横幅の意味を尋ねる本質問とは別質問になっていると思います。新規に質問として投稿することをお勧めします。

Answer (score 0):

最大化していない通常のウィンドウだと、上下左右にドラッグして画面サイズを変更できる領域があると思うんですが
それが8pxあるはず？なので、最大化した時にその部分は画面外にはみ出るので
1936×1096になるということだと思います。

windowsのテーマをクラシックに変えると、その枠分がわかりやすいかと。

Comment: なるほど、わかりました。ありがとうございました。